# Improve Linq SQL query performance

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, linq

I have the following LINQ query that runs on a 1 million records table:

```
var result = await lmsDb.SendGridEvents
 .Where(s => s.InternalId == internalId && s.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower())
 .Select(s => new MailEventDTO
 {
   InternalId = s.InternalId,
   Email = s.Email,
   error = s.error,
   Event = s.Event,
   Reason = s.Reason,
   Response = s.Response,
   Url = s.Url,
   TimeStamp = s.TimeStamp
  })
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.TimeStamp) // get the latest
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

return result;
```

How can I improve the performance of this query? Started to become really really slow.

Comment: Do you have indexes created on InternalId and Email column?

Comment: @Chetan can I create indexes on those columns even though the column values are not unique? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes.. you can always create non-cluster indexes on a column or a group of columns for which you are frequently running where clause.. What database you are using? SQL server or MySQL?

Comment: @Chetan I am using SQL server that runs on Azure.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: if you are only looking for the first element, it might by faster to skip the ordering and only take an element having MAX( timestamp )

Comment: apply email.ToLower()  outside the loop so it is not called for every element

Comment: Do you use these objects in update/delete flows? If not, use `.AsNoTracking()` to remove the entities from the EntityTracker to increase performance.

Comment: Don't call `s.Email.ToLower()`; that will likely cause SQL Server to skip *any* index you have on the `Email` column in the database and will cause a table scan, instead of a index lookup.

Comment: make a computed column on your table which is LOWER(Email) and is persistent, then index this field on not unique, then search for this field without specifying ToLower on it, but your search parameter must still be converted to lower - that way you get a nice indexed search on a lower case email version

Answer (score 1):

Check the collation setting on your database. If it is `_CI_` this will perform case insensitive string comparisons so you do not need to perform explicit case conversions. This will allow SQL Server to utilize indexes for the Email address. If it's `_CS_` this is case sensitive which will be a crimper on your performance. In that case pre-case the variable and just apply the `ToLower` on the entity value in the expression.

The next step would be to look at the database advisor for Azure SQL in the environments that you are experiencing the performance issues, typically in production. This will give you an overall view of the performance of the database including providing suggestions for index changes based on the types of queries running.

For SQL Server I like to capture the actual queries being run using a profiler, then execute these individually to inspect the execution plan being used, as well as look for any index suggestions. For instance at a guess for this query you would likely want an index on the combination of InternalId ASC, Email ASC, and Timestamp DESC. If you are using a `_CS_` collation then I suspect Email might be better off *not* in the index, but ultimately base the index addition/change/deletions off the suggestions from the advisor. When it comes to index creation, look at the suggestions from the tooling as creating the wrong indexes just lead to storage bloat and performance costs with no benefit.

This should give you a few initial places to start looking into.